# Odata extracting for deleting bookings contacts

Tags: odata

We are using Bookings to allow contacts to create appointments.
Unfortunately, Bookings stores the information in a 'contacts'
database that we are not interested in using. I would like to purge
this data regularly. I'm trying to extract the odata from a 'get' and
create a 'delete' call to Microsoft Graph

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
string graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/MallLocation@acme.ca/customers/?$select=id&$top=1";
            //Set the scope for API call to user.read
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The GET command returns ODATA, and a list of ID's, which I want to delete with a Delete Command

```
        if (authResult != null)
        {
            ResultText.Text = await GetHttpContentWithToken(graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);
            DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
            this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         }
    }
```

I've started to build the delete...but I'm new to this and struggling to write a 'for next' or 'while' statement to loop thru each ID.

```
    public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
    {
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    public async Task<string> DeleteHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
    {
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Delete, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```